# No source available for "libstdc++-6..."

Tags: c++, gcc, dll, linker, mingw-w64

I cannot run my program built using MinGW-w64 and Eclipse as IDE. As soon as I run it, without any output in the console, the message "myprog.exe has stopped working" from windows appers. The code is fine but when I exclude from building a particular file it works.

My personal guess is that it has nothing to do with the code (because I tested it in another project), it is the combination of code files that causes this problem.
In the debug perspective of Eclipse informes me that

> No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZSt9use_facetISt9money_putIwSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEEERKT_RKSt6locale() at 0x6fcb9c0a"

[image: No source available for "libstdc++-6!_ZSt9use_facetISt9money_putIwSt19ostreambuf_iteratorIwSt11char_traitsIwEEEERKT_RKSt6locale() at 0x6fcb9c0a"]
Someone suggested to add these flags in the linker option:

```
-static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc
```

It didn't work but the errore message was different:

> No source available for "std::local_Rb_tree_decrement() at 0x47379a"

[image: No source available for "std::local_Rb_tree_decrement() at 0x47379a"]

The main is a simple Hello World print.

Comands:

```
21:01:55 **** Rebuild of configuration Debug for project autoMath ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\Operator.o ..\core\Operator.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o autoMath.o ..\autoMath.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operand\Integer.o ..\core\operand\Integer.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operand\Variable.o ..\core\operand\Variable.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operand\Constant.o ..\core\operand\Constant.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operand\Vector.o ..\core\operand\Vector.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operand\OperandCore.o ..\core\operand\OperandCore.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\Op.o ..\core\Op.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operator\Unary.o ..\core\operator\Unary.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operator\OperatorCore.o ..\core\operator\OperatorCore.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\operator\Binary.o ..\core\operator\Binary.cpp 
g++ -std=c++1y -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o core\Operand.o ..\core\Operand.cpp 
g++ -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -o autoMath core\operator\Unary.o core\operator\OperatorCore.o core\operator\Binary.o core\operand\Vector.o core\operand\Variable.o core\operand\OperandCore.o core\operand\Integer.o core\operand\Constant.o core\Operator.o core\Operand.o core\Op.o autoMath.o
```

EDIT: Source code of the file that make the execution fail

```
//Binary.hpp
#include "OperatorCore.hpp"
#include "../../utility/StaticPool.hpp"
class Binary final : public OperatorCore, public StaticPool<Binary> {
    friend class StaticPool<Binary>;
public:
    enum IDs {SUM = 0, SUB, MUL, DIV, POW};
protected:
    Binary(IDs ID, std::string name, int precedence, bool revOrder = false);
public:
    const bool isAssociative;
    const bool revOrder;
    ~Binary();
    std::string print(bool latex = false) const;
    operator int() const;
};
//Binary.cpp
#include "Binary.hpp"
template<>
const Binary StaticPool<Binary>::pool[] = {
        {Binary::SUM, "+", 1}//deleting this line fix the problem
};
Binary::Binary(IDs ID, std::string name, int precedence, bool revOrder) :
        OperatorCore(name, precedence, name), StaticPool<Binary>(ID), isAssociative(true), revOrder(revOrder) {}
Binary::~Binary() {}
std::string Binary::print(bool latex) const {return name;}
Binary::operator int() const {return ID;}
```

Class "Unary" is exactly the same but it doesn't make the program fail

Comment: My guess is that it *is* a problem in your code.  Sometimes, your program will work with one toolchain but fail in another, but it only works by accident in the first place.  You may have a corrupted heap.

Comment: The message about missing sources should be from the debugger, and only appears because the program is crashing in the first place.

Comment: How can I verify that if the execution doesn't reach main (I'm new to C/C++)?

Comment: It looks like the crash occurs before `main()`, when global constructors are being called.  I say this because `__do_global_ctors()` is in the stack trace.

Comment: But also that is No source available for "__do_global_ctors() at 0x405245"

Comment: You don't need source for `__do_global_ctors()` because that's not where the bug is.  The bug is in your code.

Comment: This is the part of code that make the program fail, is it bad?
`class Binary: public StaticPool<Binary> {/*body*/}

/* -- Binary.cpp -- */
template<>
const Binary StaticPool<Binary>::pool[] = {
 Binary(args), ...
};`

Comment: Probably something in the `...` or `/*body*/` is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the "No source available" message.  You get this message because you are using the debugger to look at stack frames which are executing functions in the standard library, and the source code for the standard library is not available.  It is okay that the source is unavailable, because the bug is probably not in the standard library anyway.

It is *phenomenally rare* to encounter bona fide bug in your toolchain.

### How to read a stack trace

I created a small program that crashes on my system.

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> v { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3 };
    std::sort(std::begin(v), std::begin(v) + 16);
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it in gdb, I get the following stack trace:

```
#0  0x00007ffff7246107 in __GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6)
    at ../nptl/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:56
#1  0x00007ffff72474e8 in __GI_abort () at abort.c:89
#2  0x00007ffff7284044 in __libc_message (do_abort=do_abort@entry=1, 
    fmt=fmt@entry=0x7ffff7376c60 "*** Error in `%s': %s: 0x%s ***
")
    at ../sysdeps/posix/libc_fatal.c:175
#3  0x00007ffff728981e in malloc_printerr (action=1, 
    str=0x7ffff7376e20 "free(): invalid next size (fast)", ptr=<optimized out>)
    at malloc.c:4996
#4  0x00007ffff728a526 in _int_free (av=<optimized out>, p=<optimized out>, 
    have_lock=0) at malloc.c:3840
#5  0x0000000000401456 in __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<int>::deallocate(int*, unsigned long) ()
#6  0x00000000004010ca in std::allocator_traits<std::allocator<int> >::deallocate(std::allocator<int>&, int*, unsigned long) ()
#7  0x0000000000400dba in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::_M_deallocate(int*, unsigned long) ()
#8  0x0000000000400b95 in std::_Vector_base<int, std::allocator<int> >::~_Vector_base() ()
#9  0x0000000000400a6b in std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> >::~vector() ()
#10 0x0000000000400878 in main ()
```

You can see that frame #10 is in my code, but frames #0-9 are in the standard library.  That's relatively normal.  You'll also notice that the crash occurred after the incorrect code has finished executing: the call to `std::sort()` is what *causes* the crash, but the crash doesn't happen until `main()` returns.

Debugging crashes can be pretty tricky.

### Tools for finding the error

You are using MinGW, which is GCC, which means you *might* have access to the address sanitizer.  Try adding `-fsanitize=address` to your compilation and linking flags for debug builds.

When I compile my test program with `-fsanitize=address`, the program crashes in `std::sort()`, which is much closer to where the actual error is in `main()`.  The address sanitizer will make your program crash more quickly so it will be easier to debug.

A similar tool is Valgrind.

### Where is the error?

I can only guess, because I can't see any of your source code.  But it looks like there is a bug in the constructor for `Binary`, or maybe a global variable with type `Binary` is constructed in the wrong way.  Remember that global variables may be initialized in any order, so your code may crash if it uses any global variables which haven't been initialized yet.  This is an extremely common source of errors in C++ programs.

Comment: With that flag I get `C:/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lasan`
`collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @biowep: It  looks like the address sanitizer library is not installed on your system, but GCC supports using it if it is installed.

Comment: I found the problem, it was in the constructor of the base class. The example with the vector inspired a lot. Thank you!